# Mysql Subquery With Left Join Help Needed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I need little help regarding below query. Query is working fine but with a little logical error. I spent 4 hours to resolve it by myself but did not successful.

```
SELECT family_id, fees_term_id, fees_head_id, fees_head_name, full_name, fees_amount, paid FROM (
SELECT st.family_id, st.fees_head_id, st.fees_term_id, fh.fees_head_name, ft.full_name, 
SUM(st.fees_amount) AS fees_amount, SUM(fp.paid) AS paid
    FROM fees_students_setup st
    LEFT JOIN fees_head fh ON fh.fees_head_id = st.fees_head_id
    LEFT JOIN fees_term ft ON ft.fees_term_id = st.fees_term_id
    LEFT JOIN fees_paid fp ON fp.fees_head_id = st.fees_head_id
      AND fp.fees_term_id = st.fees_term_id
      AND st.family_id = fp.family_id
      AND fp.academic_start = st.academic_start
      AND fp.academic_end = st.academic_end
    WHERE st.family_id = '316'
    AND st.academic_start = '2013-04-01'
    AND st.academic_end = '2014-03-31'
    AND st.fees_term_id BETWEEN '1' AND '1'
    GROUP BY st.fees_head_id, st.fees_term_id
    ORDER BY st.fees_term_id
) st
;
```

This query producing below output.
[image]
The problem is with paid column. I've two tables (fees_setup) & (fees_paid). In my (fees_setup) table there are two admission fees entries for two family students. When operator paid half fees. it is doubling the entry. In my (fees_paid) table there is one entry exist admission fee = 1500. But in output it is doubling as you can see above in output. I know why this problem is due to group statement. Please view my query and please let me know if there is any chance to sum fees_paid column one time. Should i need to use subquery for this purpose? Any idea please...

Comment: You are grouping by two columns, `st.fees_head_id, st.fees_term_id`. `fees_head_id` has two values for this scenario, that's why you have two rows. Maybe you want to group by `family_id, fees_term_id` but it's difficult to guess without knowing the system in more details.

Comment: Hello Andrew thanks for reply. There is no need for group by family_id because i want to show the list of fees_head_name wise. That's i can't use family. otherwise it return single record. same goes to fees_term_id wise. Any other solution which just sum fees_paid column without repeating the fees_head_id?

Comment: What expected output do you want to see?

Comment: Would need a bit more details (eg, test data and table declares) to help more. However when this happens it is because when you join 2 tables you get every combination of the 2 tables rows based on their join conditions. Not a problem with a normal one to many relationship where you want to sum the many. But here you have a many to one, and the one is being counted many times. To get around this you need to use a sub query to get each of the totals (grouped as appropriate) and join that sub query to your main query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested (not enough details to do so), but doing a sum off the fees pain in  a sub query and then joining that would give you something like this:-

```
SELECT st.family_id, 
    st.fees_head_id, 
    st.fees_term_id, 
    fh.fees_head_name, 
    ft.full_name, 
    SUM(st.fees_amount) AS fees_amount, 
    fp.paid
FROM fees_students_setup st
LEFT JOIN fees_head fh ON fh.fees_head_id = st.fees_head_id
LEFT JOIN fees_term ft ON ft.fees_term_id = st.fees_term_id
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT fees_head_id, fees_term_id, family_id, academic_start, academic_end, SUM(paid) AS paid
    FROM fees_paid
    GROUP BY fees_head_id, fees_term_id, family_id, academic_start, academic_end
) fp
ON fp.fees_head_id = st.fees_head_id
  AND fp.fees_term_id = st.fees_term_id
  AND st.family_id = fp.family_id
  AND fp.academic_start = st.academic_start
  AND fp.academic_end = st.academic_end
WHERE st.family_id = '316'
AND st.academic_start = '2013-04-01'
AND st.academic_end = '2014-03-31'
AND st.fees_term_id BETWEEN '1' AND '1'
GROUP BY st.fees_head_id, st.fees_term_id
ORDER BY st.fees_term_id
```

Note that the GROUP BY here is not to SQL standards. You should have all the non aggregate columns in it. In this case if there were multiple values of (say) fees_head_name for a fees_head_id / fees_term_id combination then which value of fees_head_name that is returned would be undefined (could be any of the potential values).

In this case you might well just be able to add the extra column names to the GROUP BY clause

Comment: This idea is very helpful. thanks sharing it. Actually i was confused about subquery with the left join. But this syntax is working like a charm to me. thanks

Comment: I don't know but i got negative mark for this question. If some body think it write question plz give my question rating thanks.

Comment: Don't know who down voted your question, but for future reference it is best to paste in full table declares and some sample data that allow the problem to be recreated, pasted as text rather than images so people can easily copy and paste them to test themselves. Some people chose to down vote because of this.